# Nginx dynamic proxy

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to pass captured regex group as URI.

**Config:**

```
location ~ /proxy/(.*?)$ {
   proxy_pass http://$1;
}
```

**Needed:**

`http://127.0.0.1:9999/proxy/example.com/test/asd.html`
should proxy pass to:
`http://example.com/test/asd.html`

**Result:**

```
> curl http://127.0.0.1:9999/proxy/example.com/test/asd.html

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The error log is empty.
What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: well, here is what I had to do for the regex. I took your input string and tried with JS regex   let str = "http://127.0.0.1:9999/proxy/example.com/test/asd.html";
let result = str.match(/proxy\/(.*)$/);
console.log(result[1]);    ==>
example.com/test/asd.html       so you either escape '/'right after proxy just like I did to get example.com/test/asd.html or capture it in the groupd and use proxy_pass http:/$1;    ==>note only one forward slash

Comment: see if the below block of code works .. I pasted that in answer block to show the code clearly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried looking up NGINX location regex to see how the regex object works (that is // in JS) and here is what you should try

```
 location ~ \/proxy\/(.*?)$ {
 proxy_pass http://$1;
}
```

see if that helps

Comment: Now, it works for IP addresses only. If I use a domain, 404 error. If I use an IP address, for example: `http://127.0.0.1:9999/proxy/1.2.3.4` proxy passes to `http://1.2.3.4/proxy/1.2.3.4`. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe regex part is fine if it worked for ip addresses. I think you should make sure that the domain names are configured to the right IP addresses? is there a way for you to print out "proxy_pass" some how?

Comment: I don't think so. I will try it though. Edit: I see resolver error in logs. Added `resolver 8.8.8.8` and now it can resolve domain names. But, I still have problems. 1- It doesn't pass Host header when a proxy passing to a domain name. 2- This happens: `example.com/proxy/example.com`

Comment: Fixed proxy header thing by capturing two groups. `\/proxy\/(.*?)\/(.*?)`

Comment: great that `resolver` solved some more problems. can you explain a bit more about your points 1 and 2 from above comment?